# [Vue 3][Composition API] Child Props Bind affect the Parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Description:

I'm currently working on a Vue 3 project and encountering difficulties with props binding and copying. I've read the documentation and tried a few approaches, but I'm still facing the following issue:

While Parent component init the data, the child component is consuming the Data with props.
The child component has it own "local state" with ref and when init the child components the "local state" is init with the props that for some reason also change the parent while the "local state" is chaning:

```
const props = defineProps({
  objectDataFromParent: {
    type: Object
  },
});

const localState = ref({})

onMounted(async () => {
  
localState.value = props.objectDataFromParent // this I assume create the bind and also affect the parent for some reason while props is read only

});
```

What I've Tried:

Since for some reason the bind is too strong in Vue 3 (this thing didnt happend to me in vue 2 I assume since of option API. The Bind of the local state to the props affect also the parent, that means that every change of "localState" it affect the parent props that affect again the "localState" and gets into infinite loop.

```
The solution that I have tried is:

1. Make a cloneDeep with lodash (Didnt work since of Proxy object of the props I assume).
2. Cancel the props reactivity with JSON.parse(JSON.strigify())...
3. Make the bind as is and then point on a specific attribute (key) that I would like and then make of it a shallowCopy :

shallowCopyOfAttribute.value = {...localState.value.randomKey}
```

I would like to understand few things :

1. What is the best approach for this situation while I dont want to manipulate the Parent props.
2. Why does it happens ?
3. When would you use the "powerful binding" of bind a props to localState that change the parent.

I really thought its a Vue bug but in a lot of research explanined that this is expected behavior of VUE 3 Setup API.

Thanks for the reading and hope that we will have a wonderful time :)

Comment: Consider updating or reasking the question if there's something that dupe questions don't answer. The reason is very specific, an object is a reference and the same object is being reused between comps until you explicitly clone it, this is general JS topic that isn't specific to Vue. Any of the listed "solutions" will work, none of them is "best". It's unknown what you did in Vue 2 and why cloneDeep didn't work, the question is unspecific and lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EstusFlask My friend, I truly know that JS object is a reference but as you know Props in child cant change a local value in the Parent component, thats why I was asking this question.

If you are a vue expert or JS expert please give me a real answer of the question otherwise dont close my ticket.

Comment: I voted on close because currently this looks like a full duplicate of existing questions. You physically can't change a prop like `props.objectDataFromParent = ...` because props object properties are read-only. You "can't" change nested properties like `props.objectDataFromParent.foo = ...` because this is a bad practice, but there's no physical restriction. The question probably results from the wrong interpretation.

Comment: @EstusFlask So explain to me why the copy of the props or the bind of the props to a local state in the child component change directly the parent local state with out emitting anything.

This is what I truly ask since Im not chaning directly the Props, Im changing the bind of it in the local State of the child and not exepcted anything to be changed on the parent unless Im emitting something.

Please reopen the question since the answers its not satisfying and I truly need an answer for it.

Comment: `localState.value` holds a reference to `props.objectDataFromParent` and so the object from the parent that was passed through props. `localState.value.foo = 2` will make `props.objectDataFromParent.foo === 2` and `objectDataFromParent.foo === 2` in a parent. And this is already discussed in linked posts and not specific to Vue, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25117245/3731501 . The answer would be a copy of existing posts, and this the reason why dupes aren't allowed on SO. I'd be glad to address your case if it's different in some way but currently the question doesn't describe it enough